# Post thumbnail jump in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I would like to ask how to modify CSS that IE's post-thumbnail does not work. I need the post to be aligned side by side and not below. In Firefox and Chrome is ok. I thank you so much for a help.

Url - [bvjournal.cz/aktuality](http://bvjournal.cz/aktuality)

Screenshot IE (bad): https://ibb.co/hmA4Fn

Screenshot Firefox (good): http://ibb.co/nDd21S

Comment: you have used flex which is not supported in ie [see](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: Ok, can you help me with modification, please?

Comment: If you want to keep using flex layout, [plugin](https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility) available (I haven't tried it this yet), or try to make it using bootstrap 3 gid layout